# Does blocking URL parameters in Google Search Console remove pages from index?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index, url-parameters

In GSC there is a possibility of telling Google how to deal with URL parameters. Google suddenly started to index 600k+ URLs with parameters on our website. I have set the parameter in GSC as uncrawlable and about 400k pages dissapeared from index. So i thought everyting works as expected and the rest of the pages will be removed as well. After a month there is 300k pages again indexed.

Should It work and should I wait or do I have to set the pages as noindex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would set them definitely to noindex. Beside of this i would create special sitemap containing only noindex-ed urls and push it to the GSC. Make sure, that parametrized urls **aren't** blocked by robots.

Answer (score 0):

May be you did not setup all URL Parameters correctly.
Google stopped supporting noindex command in ROBOTS.Txt and It is hard to use it URL Wise.

So You should use URL Parameters correctly.